# Optomechanis and building optical setups

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I switched fields and am new to optics and optomechanics also my high school optics is not the best. I will have to design and build a lot of optical setups in my new field and was wondering if someone can recommend me a quick way to learn all about each individual Opto-mechanical component and why we place it there, and how to align it build it etc.?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am sorry to break it to you, but you need a supervisor. The scope of your question is too broad to easily answer here and it really requires a hands-on approach.

Comment: I wondered if there was a book on this stuff too, when I first started building optical setups, but as far as I know there is not ... it seems all to spread by word of mouth through each lab.